# Is $x=-2n$ the solution of :$ \operatorname{erf}(1-x) +\zeta(x)=1$ with $n$ is a positive integer?

Tags: riemann-zeta, error-function

let $x$ be a real number , I want to know if $x=-2n$ with $n$ is a positive integer   is a  solution of this equation:$$ \operatorname{erf}(1-x) +\zeta(x)=1$$   as [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf(+1-x)%2Bzeta(x)%3D1) by wolfram alpha , however wolfram alpha gaves us a real solution which is :$1.87...$, then I'm very interesting to know how the titled equation could be solved using any represenation of zeta and erf functions ?

Comment: $\zeta(-2n)$ are zero for $n = 1, 2, \cdots$, and $\operatorname{erf}(1-2n)$ approaches to $1$ super-exponentially fast as $n\to\infty$, which explains why zeros are numerically very close to $-2n$, but of course they are not exact zeros.

Comment: @SangchulLee, what about 1.87..... ?

Comment: Notice that $\operatorname{erf}(1-x) + \zeta(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 1^+$ and $\operatorname{erf}(1-x) + \zeta(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. So it must attain a zero in $(1, \infty)$, which just happens to have value $1.8726440324422977056\cdots$. But I see no particular meaning of this zero...